# Make JavaScript script load after render in a huge React.JS webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with React.JS. On my index.html of my WebApp, I load "script.js", which is in charge of making several things interactive (menu, search button, ...).

However, in some Components I use an element that is initialized when I load "script.js".

So, this element is not initialized when loading "script.js" (because "script.js" is loaded before render).

Knowing that this is a big WebApp, and that it wouldn't be clean to add a line of code to append a  tag each time in a componentDidMount() function, would you have an idea of how I could do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe just load this script in head (index), before render but wrap all needed functionality in function. store ref to this function somewhere on global (window) and then on didMount just call this needed function.

Comment: Thank you Robert, for helping me !
I will try to export the function that init the element. And call it when needed... Gonna be hard. Here is the code of script.js : https://pastebin.com/i6xUJqK7

The element is ".toggle-search", and the function associated which init the element is r.Ani.formSearch().

Comment: good luck don't look friendly after minification.

Comment: The ReactDOM API supports callback for when the React has rendered. Maybe the script.js can be loaded in this way after the React has been mounted?
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dWz3LsiZ

Tried that... but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @robert and @Kunukn, I've "succeed" to code it.

In my "script.js", at the end of the file I set `window.searchInit = r.Ani.formSearch`

And in my Component's componentDidMount() function, I call `window.searchInit('.toggle-search');`

Not clean as expected... But it works !